# MongoDB Backups - Is it safe to snapshot only the dbpath volume?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Assumption: Single MongoDB instance.

I have tested a backup and restore using an EBS snapshot of only the volume storing my data (dbpath) and NOT the /logs or /journal volumes.  The restore seems to work fine and the data is available.

Are there any risks or downsides to doing this?  In other words, do I lose anything if I don't have a backup snapshot of the /logs and /journal volumes?

Comment: Logs does not matter, but journal does. Its also a good idea to run the backup on a replica that is not the primary, that way you can lock the volume before running the snapshot.

Comment: @datasage Thanks for the reply! When does the /journal matter?  What I mean is, I was able to successfully backup and restore using only /data.

Comment: There is a very small window of time (should be 30 ms) where data an operation may exist in the journal, but not yet in the data files. But if you lock the database before initiating the snapshot, you should be ok.

Comment: Ok - so if I'm planning to do an hourly backup (which means I forgo up to 60 minutes of data in a disaster) then the 30ms of journal probably doesn't matter, right?

Comment: It comes down to the volume of write operations. If the volume is fairly low, the chance of of missing a write in the journal is pretty tiny. If you have a high volume of writes, then the probability increases.

Answer (score 5):

#### Backing up if journal and dbpath are on *separate* EBS volumes

If your `/journal` directory is on a different EBS volume from your `dbpath`, the only way to get a consistent backup would be to use [`db.fsyncLock()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.fsyncLock/) to ensure there are no pending write operations. The `fsyncLock()` command has the side effect of blocking all writes to your database, so typically you would only want to use this approach if you are backing up from a secondary in a replica set (rather than a sole `mongod`, as per your assumption in the question description).

#### Backing up if journal and dbpath are on the *same* EBS volumes

If the `journal` and `dbpath` are on the same EBS volume you can get a [consistent backup using EBS snapshots](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/backup-and-restore-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/#backup-the-database-files).

#### Do you need to backup the log directory?

Strictly speaking, you do not need to backup the logs. For troubleshooting purposes it can be useful to [rotate the logs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/logRotate/) and keep a few days of recent log files.

> I have tested a backup and restore using an EBS snapshot of only the volume storing my data (dbpath) and NOT the /logs or /journal volumes. The restore seems to work fine and the data is available.

This approach will be fine, until it isn't -- that fateful day when you want to need to restore from backup and realise that your last *n* backups are unusable as you try them one at a time, or perhaps encounter unexpected errors days after you assumed a restored database was OK.  If you don't backup the journal file this is effectively the same as running without journaling, and the [recommended recovery procedures](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/) involve running a repair before restarting.  The risk isn't so much about changes that haven't been flushed from the journal, but rather the unlucky timing if the power goes out in the middle of a write to the data files leaving things in an inconsistent state with no recovery information (aka: the journal).

If you're going to take backups, definitely follow the correct procedure to remove unnecessary risk.

For more information see [EC2 Backup and Restore](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/backup-and-restore-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/) in the MongoDB manual.

Comment: This advice seems to be true if you care about the journal.  My question is focused on whether or not a backup is valid without the corresponding journal and the answer is clearly (by practice) yes.  I have restored our database from the /data volume only and it works fine every time.  The issue of using the journal seems to be if you care about consistency at the moment of failure (or backup) which in my case hasn't been important.  Adding fsynclock requires my database to be offline which in a single-instance scenario is less than desirable.

Comment: If you have journaling enabled and don't include the journal in your backup, the answer is not "yes" for a valid backup it is "maybe". Your database could be corrupt and this may not be apparent even if things "seem to work" when you restore (thus the extra step of running a repair). If you care about the backup and data integrity, you should do it properly.  Your question was "are there any risks", and the answer is "definitely" :). The [journal exists for durability and crash recovery](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/journaling/), and ignoring it removes that guarantee.

Comment: Well said. Considering that, what do high-volume high-availability outfits do to avoid having their site/app down for the few seconds it takes to snapshot?  Right now I run a backup every hour and I would be taking the DB offline for several seconds each time if I used fsynclock.  Thoughts?

Comment: Common approaches for high availability backups are either to use EBS/filesystem snapshots or replica sets (backing up off a secondary). If your data and journal directories are on the same volume, the EBS/filesystem snapshots do *not* require you to `fSyncLock()` in order to get a consistent backup. There are also commercial options like the [MongoDB Backup Service](http://mms.mongodb.com) which provides offsite backup and point-in-time recovery.